# OpenCV Python: fast solution for 3-channel float32 image reading?

Tags: python, image, performance, opencv, image-processing

I need 3-channel RBG-ordered color images of type `float32` with their values in the interval `[0.0, 1.0]` for each color channel.

This is my current solution:

```
def read_images(imagelist):
    buffer = list()
    for f in imagelist:
        # load single image, convert to float32
        img = cv2.imread(f).astype(np.float32)
        # change interval from [0, 255] to [0.0, 1.0]
        img /= 255.0
        # leave out alpha channel, if any
        if img.shape[2] == 4:
           img = img[:, :, 0:3]
        buffer.append(img)
    return np.array(buffer)
```

Afterwards, in an image handler, I change BGR to RGB ordering (because `cv2`'s `imread` reads images in BGR order by default).

This procedure is quite time consuming for large image sets: I am loading thousands of images for pre-processing and then feed the images to some neural networks implemented in TensorFlow.

Is there a way of improving the performance of this approach?

Comment: I would suggest you not to append all the images to a buffer, simply perform this procedure for a single image before passing it to your neural network.

Comment: The thing is that batches (i.e. 4D tensors of images, like `(4, 600, 800, 3)` for 4 images of dimension 800x600 with 3 color channels) can be easily run in parallel on GPUs, thus you get a strong perfomance boost for the neural network. Additionally, it has benefits for the weight updates of the networks. This is why I want to pass several images at once.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With this approach, there's probably not too much you can do to speed up your image reading. I thought maybe Matplotlib would be faster, since it reads directly as a float and in RGB order, but it is thrice as slow as OpenCV, even after converting the type and channel order. PIL is a bit faster than Matplotlib, but still twice as slow as OpenCV so that doesn't help, and scikit-image is about the same speed as PIL:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from PIL import Image

import timeit
times = range(1000)

# matplotlib
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
for t in times:
    img = mpimg.imread('img1.png')
print("mpimg.imread(): ", timeit.default_timer() - start_time, "s")

# OpenCV
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
for t in times:
    img = cv2.cvtColor(
        cv2.imread('img1.png'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB).astype(np.float32)/255.0
print("cv2.imread(): ", timeit.default_timer() - start_time, "s")

# scikit-image
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
for t in times:
    img = io.imread('img1.png').astype(np.float32)/255.0
print("io.imread(): ", timeit.default_timer() - start_time, "s")

# PIL
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
for t in times:
    img = np.asarray(Image.open('img1.png')).astype(np.float32)/255.0
print("Image.open(): ", timeit.default_timer() - start_time, "s")
```

> mpimg.imread():  37.68960806101677 s
>   cv2.imread():  13.830177563999314 s
>   io.imread():  29.395271296001738 s
>   Image.open():  26.633562815986807 s

Instead it might be better to preprocess by reading through all the images and saving them to a better format for reading (that is, directly reading from bytes) instead of using image readers. You can serialize (pickle) your images into `.p` or `.pickle` files, and then load the data directly into a list. That way you just have to do the slow loading once and once only. As [Dan Mašek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek) notes below in the comments, pickling your files means uncompressing them into raw data, so the files sizes *will* be far larger. You can create your same list as you have now (your buffer) with the correct type and channel ordering, and then pickle the list; when it comes time to train you can load the pickle file; it's *way* faster, and super simple:

```
with open(training_file, mode='rb') as f:
    training_data = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: Well put. Nice performance testing and using pickle makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @daniel451 Also spread the loading of the whole set of images between multiple threads, that ought to help a bit as well. Also, keep in mind that the preprocessed data will a) not use compression b) is 4x larger, so the result will be much more I/O heavy.

Comment: @DanMašek great points, I'll make a note of that in the post as well.