# Most efficient way to read in a JPEG image and determine brightness

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I'm using the method below to get perceived brightness. I'm curious if there are faster ways to do this?

```
def brightness( im_file ):
   im = Image.open(im_file)
   stat = ImageStat.Stat(im)
   r,g,b = stat.rms
   return math.sqrt(0.241*(r**2) + 0.691*(g**2) + 0.068*(b**2))
```

Requirements

- Perfomance is the most important factor
- Image files are under 30KB
- Brightness will be similar across the image. There'll be small differences but looking at a fraction of the image should be sufficient.

Comment: `numpy` and `scipy` may be faster as it can greatly accelerate computation.

Comment: can you give some example's and what do you want the brightness to be? Is full white `1` and full black `0` ?

Comment: Further, I think you can use multi-thread to accelerate reading images.

Comment: @user1767754 Yeah that works.

Comment: @Sraw images are read in real time sequentially

Comment: If you need the "brightness" value just for your own comparisons, you can use a linear function. Although it'll not be scientifically correct, you'd have sped-up the process quite a bit. Would this work?

Comment: Try `vips` if you want performance https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips/wiki/Speed-and-memory-use

Comment: Of course, if you have hundreds/thousands to do, some parallelism will help you enormously.

Comment: I can do 1,000 images of 30kB each in 9s, including reading from disk, with `parallel vips im_stats {} ::: *.jpg`, so 9ms per image.

Answer (score 2):

PIL is terribly inefficient for this. PIL is implemented in pure Python, and so it's looping *in Python* through your image. Let's take a look at the implementation of the `ImageStat.Stat.rms` attribute [from the source code](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/ImageStat.py):

```
def _getrms(self):
    "Get RMS for each layer"

    v = []
    for i in self.bands:
        v.append(math.sqrt(self.sum2[i] / self.count[i]))
    return v
```

which uses the helper functions

```
def _getsum2(self):
    "Get squared sum of all pixels in each layer"

    v = []
    for i in range(0, len(self.h), 256):
        sum2 = 0.0
        for j in range(256):
            sum2 += (j ** 2) * float(self.h[i + j])
        v.append(sum2)
    return v

def _getcount(self):
    "Get total number of pixels in each layer"

    v = []
    for i in range(0, len(self.h), 256):
        v.append(functools.reduce(operator.add, self.h[i:i+256]))
    return v
```

I'm confused on why there's a function for `count`...but whatever. Anyways, as is evidenced here, this is highly inefficient. The above can be written much more efficiently directly with numpy functions.

---

Further, OpenCV is far faster at reading images than PIL. From one of [my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45892102/5087436), I timed the standard libraries for reading images and OpenCV was the fastest.

---

Lastly I don't think you should be summing the RMS with a Euclidean distance function for two reasons:

1. The weights you used are of the type used to convert between grayscale images which is multiplied and added linearly.
2. If the images are floats, then this scales the values *down*, whereas if the values are `uint8`, then this scales values *up*. I'm not sure if you actually *want* that type of scale. I think a linear scale makes it easier.

I'm also unsure of the weights you've used here, 0.068 for blue is very small (only 6% of brightness?). The [YUV standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) uses the following weights:

```
Y = 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B
```

---

With that said my answer doesn't provide the *actual* code to solve your problems so you should select the one that does, like `user1767754`'s answer. I just wanted to point out some of the reasons why PIL is slow here.

Comment: It's good that you are mentioning the implementation details and the speed relation between PIL and CV +1!

Answer (score 1):

So here is one solution that is on aver almost twice faster:

> **Timing Stats: 10000 Runs**
>       Sum Methods: **9.4s**
>       ImageStat (Yours): **24.s**

1) Calculate Sum of all Pixels

2) Calculate Sum of a perfectly white image

3) Now map the calculated sum of pixels between `0` (black) and `1`(white)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

#Load Image
img1 = cv2.imread('testing_1.png',3) #READ BGR

width, height, depth = img1.shape
maxValue = width * height * depth * 255
imageValue = np.sum(img1)

#Map Value between 0 and 1
m = interp1d([0,maxValue],[0,1])
print m(imageValue)
```

> Test1: A very dark image: Value: 0.126771993983

[image]

> Test1: A very bright image: Value: 0.65562396666

[image]

Comment: Note that the timing difference is both in using the libraries you used and also just reading the images; OpenCV is [twice as fast as PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45892102/5087436) at reading images.

Comment: I've actually run just open tests with `PIL.open` vs `cv.imgread` and  PIL around 6 times faster. Either it's intelligent that it knows that it's the same image in memory (I am pretty sure that  I am closing the image after reading. Or it does something magical.

Comment: It could have been the conversion to a `float` numpy array in `[0, 1]` that slowed down my test but...hm...that is interesting. Maybe should apply the tests to a large database.

Comment: I've followed your post with the tests and run it on my machine, that might be totally true when you do the conversions. I've actually just downloaded a 200 MB file, let's see what this tests tells.

Answer (score 0):

[ImageStat.Stat](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagestat.htm) can work on only a region of the image:

> **ImageStat.Stat(image, mask)** ⇒ Stat instance
>
> Calculates statistics for the give image. If a mask is included, only
>   the regions covered by that mask are included in the statistics.

You say that brightness will be similar across the entire image, so you can choose a mask size that is as small as possible for your use case. The smallest possible mask size is of course a single pixel. But I guess that most of your images might not be completely gray, so you can increase the mask size until you find a value that is satisfactory for you.

There are methods you can use to try to find the optimal mask size. Have a bunch of test images. Calculate their brightness without a mask, as well as with different sizes of the mask. Then check what difference you get. Try to minimize the difference.

Also try to pick different regions and shapes: Center, left corner, square, round, every other pixel. As Alexander Reynolds points out in the comments, a mask with random pixels might be the best option since it represents the entire image without bias.

Comment: I imagine that a random mask would probably be best for minimizing the number of checked pixels while biasing your tests as least as possible.

Comment: Right, of course. Random should be better than center. Thanks!