# How to optimize reading and resizing images from image location

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I currently use the following function calls to read an image of shape (3840,5760,3) from a file location (image_path) and resize it to shape (500,500,3) on Python 3.6.

```
img = cv2.imread(image_path)
img = cv2.resize(img, (500, 500))
```

I use optimized OpenCV library as on benchmarking it's performance against scipy and matplotlib reading, it gives the best performance. (Ref: http://blog.mmast.net/python-image-processing-libraries-performance-opencv-scipy-scikit-image)

However, on profiling, I find that around 35% of my code execution time goes in reading this image file from the path only. I would like to make this work efficient. Please guide me on how I can do so.

Comment: "However, on profiling, I find that around 35% of my code execution time goes in reading this image file from the path only." Why is that surprising? It needs to read the image, decode it, and put it all into memory. 35% sounds about right. You're probably not going to make this much better without launching multiple workers to load/resize images in parallel. OpenCV does read images quickly compared to other similar libs in Python, as I've tested in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45892102/5087436), so I don't see any easy way out aside from parallel processing.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Yeah, I realize that OpenCV is the best I can do at the moment. Still on the lookout for faster alternatives, if possible. Parallel processing seems like a good alternative but I can not allocate multiple workers for this script due to resource management issues. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Of course, you can also write this in C++ instead of Python for a little bit of a speedup. With that addition you can try seeing if running on a GPU helps you out, if you are compiled with `cuda` support. For example, see [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/185261/gpu-vs-cpu-end-to-end-latency-for-dynamic-image-resizing/). Actually, I'd probably first see if using `ImageMagick` is faster since it's a super easy command line interface that is quite snappy, and you could easily write a bash script for processing tons of images.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I already have a trained model and I'm importing the weights from there, so GPU optimization wouldn't help a lot in classification only.
I tried using Wand, an optimized library for ImageMagick, but it returns the image of the type <class 'wand.image.Image'> instead of numpy or scalar, which is the expected input of OpenCV's module SIFT.