# Load a image.png in a few milliseconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to perform a function on images in less than 1 second. I have a problem on a 1000x1000 image that, just to load it as a matrix in the program, takes 1 second.

The function I use to load it is as follows:

```
import png

def load(fname):

    with open(fname, mode='rb') as f:
        reader = png.Reader(file=f)
        w, h, png_img, _ = reader.asRGB8()
        img = []
        for line in png_img:
            l = []
            for i in range(0, len(line), 3):
                l+=[(line[i], line[i+1], line[i+2])]
            img+=[l]

        return img
```

How can I modify it in such a way that, when opening the image, it takes a little more than a few milliseconds?

IMPORTANT NOTE: I cannot import other functions outside of this (this is a university exercise and therefore there are rules -.-). So I have to get one myself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV Python: fast solution for 3-channel float32 image reading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890171/opencv-python-fast-solution-for-3-channel-float32-image-reading)

Comment: Are there functions in `Reader` other than `asRGB8` that you could call that might be faster?

Comment: I do not know this. I have, however, double-checked the code and the problem is the for loop

Comment: It's not just one for loop, it's two of them nested.  That's an O(n^2) problem which will always be slow.

Comment: Question stipulates a requirement of a few milliseconds, but does not clarify. I don't think they know what a millisecond is.  This is actually a pretty specific requirement, but seems to be used casually.  Question is as a result very unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending to a `list` is inherently slow - read about [Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).  You can replace it with a generator expression and slicing.

```
    for line in png_img:
        img += list(zip(line[0::3], line[1::3], line[2::3])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `PIL` to do this for you, it's highly optimized and fast

```
from PIL import Image

def load(path):
    return Image.open(path)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The problem is that this is a university exercise and I was ordered not to import other libraries than the ones they gave me. I have to find a way to do it with what I have and at the moment I only have this 'load' function that they gave me. But this function for the times I have to respect is not good and I have to write one myself. Can you give me some other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is remotely possible to run a python script that opens a file, etc. in just a few ms. On my computer, the simplest program takes several 10ms

Without knowing more about the specifics of your problem and the reasons for your constraint, it is hard to answer. You should consider what you are trying to do, in the context of the way your program really works, and then formulate a strategy to achieve your goal.

The total context here is, you're asking the computer to:

1. run python, load your code and interpret it
2. load any modules you want to use
3. find your image file and read it from disk
4. give those bytes some meaning as an image abstraction - parse, etc these bytes
5. do some kind of transform or "work" on the image
6. export your result in some way

You need to figure out which of those steps is it that really needs to be lightning fast. After that, maybe someone can make a suggestion.